# Circles with common tangent

Tags: geometry, circles

I am trying to solve this simple geometry problem but I am always tangled in so many equations it makes my head spin.  I tried solving it via similar triangles but i cant seem to eliminate all the unwanted variables. Please help.

I have to prove $ r_1\times r_3=(r_2)^2$

[image: Question Image]

Thank you

Comment: Hint: Try to calculate $r_2/r_1$ as function of angle BAO. You'll get that the ratio $r_2/r_1$ doesn't depend on $r_x$, only on the angle.

Comment: @lesnik should i try sine of BAO or Cosine of BAO? Would i also need to calculate the length of direct common tangent?

Comment: Imagine several more circles constructed by similar rules. $r_4, r_5, r_6,...$. Each next circle is bigger than previous one. Main idea is that the radius of the next circle is bigger than the radius of previous circle by some fixed multiplier. The problem would be almost solved if you prove this fact. The easiest way to prove it is to find this multiplier. Start with $r_1$ and angle BAO as given and try to calculate $r_2$.
Sorry I am giving only hints, but the problem looks like a homework, it wouldn't be right just to give a solution.

Comment: Draw a line through $O$ parallel to $BD$. This will intersect $PC$ at $H$ and $QD$ at $K$. Triangles  $OHP$ and $OKQ$ are similar.

Comment: @lesnik thanks bud.solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

We have
\begin{align} 
\triangle AOB:\quad
|AO| &= \frac{r_1}{\sin\phi}
,\\
|AP|&=|AO|+|OP|=\frac{r_1}{\sin\phi}+r_1+r_2
,\\
\triangle APC:\quad
|AP| &= \frac{r_2}{\sin\phi}
,
\end{align}
which gives 
\begin{align} 
r_2&=
\frac{r_1(1+\sin\phi)}{1-\sin\phi}
.
\end{align}

Similarly,

\begin{align} 
|AQ| &= |AP|+|PQ|=\frac{r_1}{\sin\phi}+r_1+2r_2+r_3
\\
&=
\frac{r_1}{\sin\phi}+r_1+
\frac{2r_1(1+\sin\phi)}{1-\sin\phi}
+r_3
,\\
\triangle AQD:\quad
|AQ| &= \frac{r_3}{\sin\phi}
,\\
\end{align}

hence

\begin{align} 
r_3&=
\frac{r_1(1+\sin\phi)^2}{(1-\sin\phi)^2}
,\\
\end{align}

and

\begin{align} 
r_1r_3&=r_2^2
\end{align}

follows.

Comment: How you draw that beautiful diagram?

Comment: @IgotiT: Thank's for asking, this is the [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/)
Vector Graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way they are constructed, the triangles $ABO,ACP,ADQ$ are similar, the figures $ABCPO$, $ACDQP$ are homothetic and $\dfrac{r_2}{r_1}=\dfrac{r_3}{r_2}.$

Comment: could you elaborate it a little please?

Comment: @SheldonCooper: don't you see the similarity (same angles) ?

Comment: Similarity by itself is not enough to conclude.

Comment: The similarity already proves the conclusion immediately. I do not know what you mean @Arerino.

Comment: @Aretino: I have added a piece of information.

Comment: Now it makes sense, +1.

Comment: On thinking again about your answer, I think it is not obvious that quadrilaterals $BCPO$ and $CDQP$ are homothetic. How do you prove it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Contacting Circles]

We have $h'$s of contacting circles from common apex A, the series of similar triangles:

$$  h_2-h_1=2r_1,  h_3-h_2=2r_2,  h_4-h_3=2r_3 \tag1$$

$$ \sin \alpha = \frac {(h_2-h_1)/2}{(h_2+h_1)/2}= \frac {h_2-h_1}{h_2+h_1} =\frac {h_3-h_2}{h_3+h_2}\tag2$$

Apply componendo/dividendo to each pair

$$\frac{1+\sin \alpha}{1-\sin \alpha}= \frac{h_2}{h_1} =  \frac{h_3}{h_2} =\frac{h_4}{h_3} = = k \tag3$$

which gives successive geometric means that are also called *powers of circle* corresponding to extreme $h$ values product of each pair:

$$ r_1=\sqrt{h_1h_2},\, r_2=\sqrt{h_2h_3},\, r_3=\sqrt{h_3h_4}  \, \tag4$$

$$ \frac{r_2^2 }{r_1 r_3}=\frac{h_2 h_3}{\sqrt{h_1h_2h_3h_4}}=\sqrt{\frac{h_2 h_3}{h_1 h_4}}=\sqrt{k/k}=1 \tag5$$